# ThemeContext value not updating

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, react-context

Am pretty new to react ,my problem is that my value is not getting updated of my themecontext.
I have been experimenting myself but it didn't work ;-;

This s themecontext provider

```
import { createContext, useState } from "react";

const Themecontext = createContext("Light");

export default Themecontext;
```

This is where i want to update my value settngs.tsx

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  StatusBar,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View,
  Switch,
} from "react-native";
import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons";
import { themeHandler } from "./CustomComponents/CustomColor";
import { useRouter } from "expo-router";
import Themecontext from "./CustomComponents/Contexts";
import { EventRegister } from "react-native-event-listeners";

function Settings(props) {
  const [getTheme, setTheme] = useState("Light");
  const getThemeHandler = themeHandler();
  const Colors = getThemeHandler.getColors();
  const router = useRouter();
  const updateTheme = () => {
    setTheme(getTheme === "Light" ? "Dark" : "Light");
    EventRegister.emit("SetTheme", getTheme);
  };

  return (
    <Themecontext.Provider value={getTheme}>
      <SafeAreaView>
        <View
          style={[
            {
              marginTop: StatusBar.currentHeight,
              backgroundColor: Colors.Background,
            },
          ]}
        >
          <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", alignItems: "center", gap: 10 }}>
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() => {
                router.push({ pathname: "dashboard" });
              }}
            >
              <View style={[{ padding: 10 }]}>
                <Icon name="arrow-back" size={30} color={Colors.Primary} />
              </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <Text style={[styles.sttingsText, { color: Colors.Primary }]}>
              Settings
            </Text>
          </View>
          <View style={[styles.settingContainer, {}]}>
            <View //Dark theme Card
              style={[
                styles.settingAttCard,
                {
                  backgroundColor: Colors.Secondary,
                  borderColor: Colors.Primary,
                },
              ]}
            >
              <Icon
                name="sunny"
                size={30}
                color={Colors.Primary}
                style={styles.icon}
              />
              <Text style={[styles.settingsAttText, { color: Colors.Primary }]}>
                Dark Mode
              </Text>

              <Switch
                value={getTheme === "Light"}
                onValueChange={() => {
                  updateTheme();
                }}
                style={[
                  styles.settingAttSwitch,
                  { borderColor: Colors.Primary },
                ]}
              ></Switch>
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </Themecontext.Provider>
  );
}

export default Settings;
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  sttingsText: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: "500",
  },
  settingContainer: { padding: 10, marginTop: 20 },
  icon: {
    justifyContent: "flex-start",
  },
  settingAttCard: {
    padding: 10,
    flexDirection: "row",
    borderRadius: 20,
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    borderWidth: 2,
    alignItems: "center",
    gap: 20,
  },
  settingsAttText: {
    fontSize: 20,
  },
  settingAttSwitch: {},
});
```

This CustomColor.Tsx

```
import { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { EventRegister } from "react-native-event-listeners";
import Themecontext from "./Contexts";

export const themeHandler = () => {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState("Light");

  useEffect(() => {
    let reg = EventRegister.addEventListener("SetTheme", (data) => {
      setTheme(data);
    });
    return () => {
      EventRegister.removeAllListeners;
    };
  });

  const getColors = () => {
    const themeCon = useContext(Themecontext);
    console.log(themeCon);
    return theme === "Light" ? CustomColor.Light : CustomColor.Dark;
  };
  const getIcon = () => {
    return theme === "Light" ? "moon" : "sunny";
  };

  return { getColors, getIcon };
};

const CustomColor = {
  Light: {
    Primary: "#02C5C5",
    Secondary: "#F5F5F5",
    Third: "#D2E9E9",
    Background: "white",
  },
  Dark: {
    Primary: "#0B60B0",
    Secondary: "black",
    Third: "#40A2D8",
    Text: "white",
    Background: "white",
  },
};

export default CustomColor;
```

I want that the switch update the themecontext's value and i can read the value from customcolor.tsx and return the colors accordingly even if the logic seems wrong i tried different ways but theme context is not updating.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to also add `setTheme` to your provider value. Like so -

```
<Themecontext.Provider value={{getTheme, setTheme}}>
```

Now, access the context as follows -

```
const {getTheme, setTheme} = useContext(Themecontext);
```

And update the theme using `setTheme` method